# Should I use (typeof(val) === 'undefined') or (val === undefined)?

Tags: javascript

This is similar to a number of other questions on SO, but not exactly the same as any I can find.

Which is the best approach for checking for an undefined value in Javascript, and why?

First example:

```
var a;
if (typeof(a) === 'undefined'){...}
```

Second example:

```
var a;
if (a === undefined){...}
```

So, the first example is comparing the name of the type to a string, and the second is comparing the variable to the undefined object, using the equality operator, which checks that the types are the same as well as the values.

Which is better?  Or are they both as good as one another?

Note that I'm not asking about any difference between undefined and null, or truthy or falsey, just which of these two methods is correct and/or better.

Comment: Afaik they're the same, as long as you either have set up your own local `undefined`, or you can trust that no idiot will redefine it to `true` or something.

Comment: `typeof` is not a function. You don't need the parens.

Comment: The first method is safer, because (A) you don't have to worry if the `undefined` variable really holds the `undefined` value, and (B) you don't have to worry about reference errors in case your operand happens to be undeclared.

Comment: Thanks @ŠimeVidas, that's a good answer.  Shame you didn't enter it as a proper answer but as a comment.  Still, I'll see if I can vote you up.

Comment: @MickSear I just summarized the existing answers below `:)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a variable doesn't exist, then you'll get a reference error when you try to use it — even if you are comparing it to `undefined`. So always use `typeof`.

```
> foo === undefined
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty.js:320:10)
> typeof foo === "undefined"
true
```

It is also possible for (bad) code to overwrite `undefined`, which would cause an undefined value to not be equal to `undefined`.

Comment: The question included the declaration (`var a`), so this will not happen in that specific scenario. In general I'll grant you're correct.

Comment: Lots of good answers and points, thanks all.  Yes, the var a was intentional.

Comment: Strict equality isn't necessary, `==` is sufficient.

Comment: Type casting isn't necessary, `===` is sufficient.

Comment: @RobG, Quentin: Both operators will perform precisely the same steps per spec, so any preference for one or the other is purely stylistic.

Comment: @TimDown—perhaps. The `===` operator is usually reserved for cases where the type of each expression is important. As *typeof* always returns a string, it should be obvious that such expressions are always compared to a string, any other comparison will result in an error (regardless of whether `===` or `==` is used), e.g. `typeof foo == undefined`.

Comment: @RobG: It depends on your habit and which operator you use by default. I've never been convinced by either David Mark correcting this kind of use of `===` or Douglas Crockford's insistence on always using `===`.

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` can be assigned a value, and the type check won't work. Unless the scope of the code is protected, e.g.

```
(function(undefined){
    var a;
    if (a === undefined) {
})();
// note called without parameter, so undefined is actually an undefined value
```

this way to check is not safe, and first one is prefered

Edit: It seems that ECMA 5 dissalows assigning value to the undefined, but still this depends on the browser implementation.

Comment: This is a great way to ensure `undefined` is truly undefined since `undefined` is definable.

Comment: You can also compare to `void 0`, but comparison to an uninitialised variable is ok too. Oh, and `undefined` does have a value, the [undefined](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.9) value. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The two methods are correct, but the `typeof` one is immune to changes to the value of `undefined`. If you need stricter checking, use `typeof()`.

In the ECMA 3 standard, you can modify the value of undefined as such:

```
undefined = "not undefined";
```

And this can lead to ugliness when comparing to `undefined` later on. In ECMA 5, this is disallowed. This means most modern browsers will not let you set the value of `undefined`, and you should be safe using `=== undefined`.

Also, if you're not even sure whether the variable you are checking has been defined, you should use `typeof`, otherwise you will get a reference error.

Comment: Assigning to `undefined` will only throw in ES5 strict mode.

Comment: There is no need for a grouping operator with `typeof`, it is an operator, not a function.